# i cant do search in react JS and get data from PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, url

`index js`

```
const express = require("express");
const app =express();
const cors =require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json);

app.get("/data", async (req, res) => { //async to make the process fast (await)
try {
   const newData= await pool.query( "SELECT * FROM interactions"); 
   //js2xmlparser.parse('newData',newData);

  
    
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    
}
});
```

`search.js`

```
mport React,{Fragment,useEffect,useState} from "react";
import jsontoxml from "jsontoxml";
//import * as JsonToXML from "js2xmlparser";

const ListInteract =() => {

const[interactions,setinteractions] = useState([])

    const getinteractions = async () => {
        try {

            const response = await fetch ("http://localhost:3000/data")
            const data = await response.json();
          // const convert= console.log(JsonToXML.parse("data", this.data));
          // jsontoxml.escape(data);
           console.log(data);
           setinteractions(data);
            
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message)
            
        }
    }
    useEffect (() => {

        getinteractions();

    },[]); //[] it to do one


return <Fragment>

 <label>drugcode</label> <input type="text" class = "mt-5"/>
 <label>diseasecode</label> <input type="text"/>
 <label>type</label> <input type="text"/> <button class="btn btn-success">Search </button>

<table class="table table-hover mt-5 text-center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>description</th>
        <th>drugcode</th>
        <th>deasasecode</th>
        <th>type</th>
        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

     {interactions.map(interact => (
   <tr key={interact.id}>
       <td>{interact.id} </td>
       <td>{interact.decription} </td>
       <td>{interact.drugcode} </td>
       <td>{interact.diseasecode} </td>
       <td>{interact.type} </td>

   </tr>

     )
        
        )}
    </tbody>
  </table>

</Fragment>
};

export default ListInteract;
```

- i have 3 text field i put data in it drugcode&diseasecode&type *
- my goal when I put the three data in text select all and show it in the table *

---

ex: drug code =222, diseasecode=333, type=1 in table i want all data in it
id =1 description="good" drugcode=222,diseasecode=333 type=1

---

- after i put the data in text i have button search when i click in it
  it will show me all data in the table *

*** thank you all ***